# Storing oracle error/query result in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE XPTO (
this_is_an_error_because_there_is_no_data_type
);
```

---

Query Result:

```
"**Error starting at line X in command:
blablabla
SQL ERROR: ORA-02263**"
```

---

Is it possible to save the query result in a table?

I'm making an "installation" script with `CREATE` tables/procedures, `GRANT`'s simple stuff, but I want to know if it's possible to save in a table the errors that may popup during the installation of my tables or whatever it is in there (in my install file **.sql**).

Any help, ideas, work around/s, would be appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Normally people just SPOOL to a file so that it can be reviewed afterwards for any errors.

Comment: Hummm that may be a good solution for my "problem". Thanks great one!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus this can be done with [SQL*Plus error logging](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG160).

Enable error logging:

```
SQL> set errorlogging on
```

Run the script:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE XPTO (
  2  this_is_an_error_because_there_is_no_data_type
  3  );
this_is_an_error_because_there_is_no_data_type
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

At the end, all errors are stored in the table `SPERRORLOG`.

```
SQL> select * from sperrorlog;

USERNAME
------------------------------------------------
TIMESTAMP
------------------------------------------------
SCRIPT
------------------------------------------------
IDENTIFIER
------------------------------------------------
MESSAGE
------------------------------------------------
STATEMENT
------------------------------------------------
JHELLER
25-JAN-16 01.43.13.000000 PM


ORA-00972: identifier is too long
CREATE TABLE XPTO (
this_is_an_error_because_there_is_no_data_type
)
```

As Tony Andrews said in the comment, `SPOOL` is the most common method for doing this.  But that's because very few SQL*Plus scripts are fully automated.  If you are aiming for true automation you'll need something like SQL*Plus error logging or `whenever sqlerror exit failure` to detect errors.

Comment: thanks! I think with both answers I can manage to find a nice approach to my problem :D.